# How to properly connect a USB-C 2.0 plug to an FT230XS module?

Tags: integrated-circuit, ftdi, usb-c, conversion

I am coming to you for advice and I also need your help. I am working on a motor control board and for the debugging side I use a USB-C 2.0 connector and a module from FTDI, the FT230XS. Here is my question, I was wondering if I could power my FT230XS with my USB-C thanks to the VBUS pins? If so, do I have to add decoupling capacitors? And I would also like to know if for the CC1 and CC2 pins I need pull-down resistors, if yes why?

Thank you in advance for your answers.[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if I could power my FT230XS with my USB-C thanks to
> the VBUS pins?

Certainly yes, the VBUS is precisely for the purpose of powering up connected devices.

> If so, do I have to add decoupling capacitors?

You don't have to, but you can if you need cleaner power. Up to 10 uF will be fine.

> And I would also like to know if for the CC1 and CC2 pins I need
> pull-down resistors, if yes why?

Yes, you have to have 5.1k pull downs on CC1 and CC2 pins. Why? because it is the requirement of Type-C connector standard. Without pull downs the source won't output any VBUS voltage.